# SSH laggy in local network when ping not running

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ping

We have multiple Jetson TX2 Ubuntu machines on our local network, and they all share the same problem. On WIFI (on the local network) SSH is extremely laggy. Generally it will take 1-2 seconds for your input to show up in the session.
When I was diagnosing it, I noticed that if I ran: `ping 10.100.0.1 -i 0.2 -s 1000` the problem would go away while ping was running.

We have tried everything from messing with the power saving in the WIFI card to changing DNS settings with no luck. Do any of you have any ideas?

WLAN config:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Nova"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: FC:EC:DA:3F:F4:0C
          Bit Rate=400 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:5  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. For some reason the power saving mode was still active even though it reported being disabled. Turning it on, then back off solved the problem

```
iwconfig wlan0 power on
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```